# Resolving Dimension Mismatch Issue When Combining Sparse Matrices for K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to combine sparse matrices for use in a K-means clustering model. The matrices correspond to various data points for candidates, and they include work experience, skills, and credentials. I've followed a series of steps, but the dimensions of the combined data are turning out to be incorrect. Here's a breakdown of my process:

1. I'm initializing empty lists (`work_data`, `skills_data`, and `cred_data`) to store sparse matrices corresponding to different data points for candidates.
2. For each candidate in the `candidates` data structure, I'm appending their work experience, skills, and credentials data (if available) to the respective lists. I'm also calculating and updating `maxw`, `maxsk`, and `maxcr` variables based on the maximum lengths of these matrices.
3. To ensure consistent dimensions, I'm padding the sparse matrices as follows:
4. For `work_data`, I'm finding the maximum number of columns and padding the matrices accordingly.
5. Similarly, I'm padding `skills_data` and `cred_data` matrices to match the maximum number of columns.

The issue arises when I attempt to combine the matrices using `hstack` and `vstack`. The dimensions of the combined matrices turn out to be incorrect.

I'm looking for insights into potential reasons for this dimension mismatch and any suggestions for resolving the issue. The ultimate goal is to prepare this combined data for input into a K-means clustering model.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: just FYI you should plug in a `print(variable_raising_the_issue.shape)` throughout your code as a way to try to figure out what's going on. If you provide your data (or at least a subset, if it's a lot of data) in your question then we can try your code ourselves. Otherwise I'd have to come up with some mock data that I think your data is like, or else I can't run your code.

Comment: I haven't tried to follow your code.  But I'm not sure that constructing matrices with iterations on `hstack/vstack` is a good idea or efficient.  Both of those `sparse` functions use `sparse.bmat` to make a new matrix.  That in turn takes the `coo` format of all input matrices, and combines those to make a new `coo` format matrix.  It may be convenient to use those functions, but the original method was to construct the `coo` format inputs for the whole matrix directly.

Comment: In any case, debugging issues like this requires a generous sprinkling of `shape` prints.

Comment: what would you suggest instead of hstack/vstack then?